# Как разделить строки на string и int, а затем записать в HashMap?

Tags: java

```
   Алексей 3000
   Дмитрий 9000
   Антон 3000
   Алексей 7000
   Антон 8000
```

Дана строка Алексей..., у меня не получается сделать так чтоб была обработка строки на string и int учитывая пробелы(их не будет на выходе), не понимаю как записать ее в массив, но ясно как записать из массива в HashMap. Хотелось бы чтоб в HashMap было следующее: {Алексей=[10000], Дмитрий=[9000], Антон=[11000]}..., а получается в консоле только Алексей=[10000]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class maps {
    public static Map<String, Long> getSalesMap(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String thisLine = null;
        HashMap<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        thisLine = br.readLine();
        String[] part = thisLine.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
        //part = thisLine.split("[^A-Z0-9]+|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])");
        for (int j = 0; j < part.length; j = j + 2) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(part[j + 1]);
            map.put(part[j], (long) a);
        }
        return map;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println(getSalesMap(reader));
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: split(“ “) (по пробелу) ??

Comment: Вы обоабатываете и ввзываете readLine только 1 раз

Comment: чтоб работало правильно необходимо чтоб было разделение по пробелу и разделение на части (part в коде), например, part[0] = Алексей, part[1] = 3000, part[2] = Дмитрий

Comment: а как сделать так чтобы вызывать readLine много раз?

Comment: readLine, читает одну строку, в примере ввода у Вас их 5

Comment: но там еще есть перевод на новую строку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если все это одна строка, то выглядеть код будет примерно так:

```
String text = reader.readLine();
String[] arr = text.split("\n");
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for (String s : arr) {
    String name = s.trim().split(" ")[0];
    Integer salary = Integer.parseInt(s.trim().split(" ")[1]);
    map.put(name, salary);
}
```

Если это все отдельные строки, то примерно так:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
String line;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String name = line.trim().split(" ")[0];
    Integer salary = Integer.parseInt(line.trim().split(" ")[1]);
    map.put(name, salary);
}
```

Comment: а как быть в таком случае если ключ несколько раз подряд, то есть как суммировать зарплаты, как привести Алексей 3000 Алексей 7000 к Алексей 10000

Comment: @plaza2009 Тогда этот ответ неверен. Замените map.put(name, salary) на map.put(name, map.getOrDefault(name, 0) + salary)

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Для суммирования значений по ключу используй метод .merge

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Reader reader = new FileReader("src/test.txt");
            System.out.println(getSalesMap(reader));
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Long> getSalesMap(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
        String name;
        long salary;

        BiFunction<Long, Long, Long> bFunc = (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue+newValue;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine() == true) {
            name = scanner.next();
            salary = scanner.nextLong();
            if (map.containsKey(name)) {
                map.merge(name, salary, bFunc);
            } else {
                map.put(name, salary);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```